# Lua - 'end' expected (to close 'function' near <eof>), don't see missing 'end'

Tags: lua

I'm getting an error saying an 'end' is missing, but I've looked at the entire code and don't see it.

```
local Grid = {}
Grid.__index = Grid
function Grid.new(w, h) do
    t = {}
    setmetatable(t,Grid)
    for i=1,w do
        t[i] = {}
        for j=1,h do
            t[i][j] = {i, j, nil}
        end
    end
    return t
end
Grid.__call = Grid.new
return Grid
```

Here is the error:

```
lua: grid.lua:15: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 3) near <eof>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `do` on the `function` line. You have an `end` matching the `function`, but none matching the (unnecessary) `do`. (Actually the compiler thinks the `end` matches the `do` and then complains when it doesn't see an `end` for the function.)

The syntax for a function body is approximately

> `function` *name*`(` *params<sub>opt</sub>* ) *block* end

(This is oversimplified see [the Lua reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11) for details.)

A `do` is not required. If it's there, it's not part of the syntax of the function body, and must be matched with a corresponding `end`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that Lua functions don't require `do`.

Comment: @Alchemist don't forget to mark the answer as "correct" by clicking on the ✅  next to it!